# What is the tag (sums-of-squares) intended for?

Tags: discussion, tagging

The tag [sums-of-squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sums-of-squares) has empty [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/sums-of-squares/info) at the moment.

Based on the name, I would expect to see there topic such as [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) or [Lagrange's four square theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) etc. (In general, mostly topics from number theory.)

But when you have a look at question actually using this tag, you will find there also questions about [the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629135/certain-step-in-the-induction-proof-sum-limits-i-0n-i2-fracnn12n), [equations containing squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633406/to-find-in-equation-a22-c), [various infinite sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489383/simplify-the-summation).

> What would be reasonable content for this tag?

I think that if this tag is supposed to be useful, then we should clarify what kind of questions it should be used for and created a reasonable tag-wiki describing this tag.

---

**EDIT:** (Jan 16 2014) I have created [tag-excerpt and tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/sums-of-squares/info) based on number-theoretical meaning of the term. Of course, if further discussion shows that we want use this tag also for some of the other meanings of the term [sum of squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares), we can include them in the tag-wiki and tag-excerpt, too.

Comment: Variants of Hilbert's $17^{th}$ problem sounds legitimate candidates for this tag.

Comment: Questions about the sum-of-squares method in optimization theory would also sound on target http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum-of-squares_optimization .

Comment: @DavidSpeyer I have posted your suggestion as an answer, so that users can vote for/against having such questions also in this tag. It is CW, feel free to edit that answer further, if you wish.

Comment: As Gerry Myerson's answer received most upvotes, I have accepted it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would restrict it to questions about representations of integers as sums of squares. But I wouldn't expect there to be lots of relevant questions, so I wouldn't mind seeing the tag expunged altogether. Those few questions that are really about representations as sums of squares could be retagged analytic-number-theory or elementary-number-theory or diophantine-equations, as appropriate.

Comment: Given that integer sums of squares questions often have a rather algebraic flavour, I think a separate sum-of-squares tag could be quite useful. However only if it is attached to the right questions.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a suggestion for the tag-excerpt and the tag-wiki, based on Gerry Myerson posts saying that this tag is for questions about [sum of squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares) in number theory.

This is suggestion for the tag excerpt:

> For questions concerning various representation of integers as sums of squares, which are studied in number theory.

This is suggestion for the tag-wiki:

> For questions concerning various representation of integers as sums of squares, which are studied in number theory.
>
> These topics include, for example:
>
> - [Pythagorean triples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) and [Pythagorean quadruples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple)
> - [Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares)
> - [Legendre's three-square theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_three-square_theorem)
> - [Lagrange's four-square theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

I am posting another answer based on [David Speyer's comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12411/what-is-the-tag-sums-of-squares-intended-for#comment48939_12411).

Questions about the [sum-of-squares method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum-of-squares_optimization) in optimization theory could also be included in this tag.

Comment: While the name suggests it, I feel that this would make it a weird tag, covering two such different topics. I am not familiar with the topic in optimization, so I don't know if it is large enough to have its own tag (and I have no idea what such a tag could then be called).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I agree with you. In any case, I think that posting this answer here so that other users can upvote/downvote would be a reasonable way to find out what other MSE users think about this.